# Combinatorics Question Explanation

Tags: combinatorics

Jenny has 3 skirts, 2 pants, and 4 shirts. How many ways can she create an outfit with one of the shirts, and either a skirt or pant?

Can someone please explain why the solution is $20$?

Comment: $4\cdot(3+2)=20$

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total shirts and pants = $3+2$

So ways she can create an outfit with one of the shirts, and either a skirt or pant will become $ 4 (3+2)$